# Only one file name allowed error

Tags: vim, sudo

Sometimes I forget to do `sudo vim` and open files to which I don't have write permission. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005/getting-root-permissions-on-a-file-inside-of-vi) and it was really helpful.

When I did `:w !sudo tee %` it asked me for a password and then the options `(O)K` and `(L)OAD`. This worked fine. But when I did `:wq !sudo tee %`, `vim` gave me an error -

```
E172: Only one file name allowed
```

Why didn't it let me go to the prompt after `wq`. I don't understand this error.

Comment: I wanted to leave a `comment` and ask those guys on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005/getting-root-permissions-on-a-file-inside-of-vi  but don't have enough `reputation` to leave a comment.

Comment: Putting `random` words `in` code `formatting` makes `your` questions `harder` to `read`. Use _italics_ or **bold** for ordinary text, if necessary, please.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll keep this in mind. Also I should put only the first occurrence of code-word in `code`, right? Don't mind me asking it here instead of meta.

Comment: You should put all code and commands in code blocks. For things like `vim` (i.e. command names that are also the app's name), I'd leave it in plain text when it's included in a plain sentence (e.g. "I use vim to do wonderful things"), but put code markings around it if it's part of a command (e.g. "When I run `vim -d ...` foo happens").

Comment: Sure thing. thanks. Can't +1 for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `:w` and `:wq` are two different commands with different options.

Here is the description of the `:w` command with the `!{cmd}` option:

```
:[range]w[rite] [++opt] !{cmd}
                    Execute {cmd} with [range] lines as standard input
                    (note the space in front of the '!').  {cmd} is
                    executed like with ":!{cmd}", any '!' is replaced with
                    the previous command |:!|.
```

Note that `:w!` and `:w !{cmd}` are two completely different things; in the former, exclamation mark means "force write", in the latter it is a sort of a pipe sign to pass the whole range of text to the subsequent command (in your case, to `tee` run as superuser, which both returns the file to vi and saves it to the filename represented by the wildcard `%`).

Sadly, there is no such option for the command `:wq`. The only other available forms of this command are `:wq!` (here the exclamation mark is not for piping to another command, but for force quit, much like `:w!`) and `:w[!] {file}`.

Comment: can I `:wq!` and forcefully save it even if I don't have the write permissions? In my case if I am not the super user?

Comment: no. But you can forcefully overwrite a file.

Comment: what good may come from this. a user can tamper with other user's data. Doesn't this look bad?

Comment: you can forcefully overwrite your own file. Vim cannot give you more permissions that the system gives you.

Comment: yes. i just cross checked it with vim